# Selenoid is not executing 5 (default) test cases in parellel

Tags: selenoid

I am doing a POC for Setting up selenoid +ggr

on 1 machine I have ggr and on other machine I have selenoid
my selenoid setup on machine has  5 instance available
[image]

but when I execute the tests I can see only 2 tests are running.

in anther project same setup is running fine

Answer (score 0):

Selenoid is just an API that executes as many browsers as you request in parallel. Make sure you are really requesting as many browser sessions in parallel as  you wish to have.

Comment: I am executing 6 feature files as I am using specflow+nunit . and this setup support for featurefile level parallel excution only

Comment: Don't have any experience with these tools.